# How to align ListView Items on Columns C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using C# windows form, I want to align the "testing" listview items on the two different column

[image]

Comment: What does "align" mean to you?

Comment: literally put "testing1" on the "full fee" column, sorry

Comment: Well, show the code on how you are populating the ListView now?  In a ListView, the SubItems go into the other columns.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, I added the items on form itself, I didn't put any codes to add items

Comment: In the designer where you added these testing items, there is a collection property called SubItems.  Add something there.

Comment: I see, first one the items is on the 1st column when I add a SubItem it goes to the 2nd column, but what do I have to do when I have more than 3 columns?

Comment: You add more columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are additional columns need to be assigned, you can refer to the following steps.

1. Click the small triangle in the upper right corner and select `Edit Items`.

   [image]
2. Select the `ListViewItem` you want to edit, and click the `‧‧‧` in `SubItems`.

   [image]
3. Add a new subitem, and enter the text.

   [image]

Hope this can help you.